# Rails: extending alias_method_chain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There is a Rails 4.2.6 application that has a core plugin extending ActiveRecord `reload` method via `alias_method_chain`.
I need to write another plugin extending the same base functionality and keeping what was added by the core plugin.
As far as I get it, I can call `alias_method_chain` only once but I wish to get something like this:

```
class Klass
  def foo
end

core_plugin:
  base.send :alias_method_chain, :foo, :bar

my_plugin:
  base.send :alias_method_chain, :foo, :baz
```

Where a call to Klass.foo results in calls to `:baz`, `:bar` and `:foo`

So what are my options assuming I cannot edit core_plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this

class Klass

```
def foo
    puts "foo"
    end
def baz
    puts "printing baz..."
bar
    puts "...printing bar"
  end

  alias_method :bar, :foo
  alias_method :foo, :baz
end

Klass.new.foo
```

prints

printing baz...
foo
...printing bar

Is this ur expectation? If not pls explain

Comment: Well, kind of, but I already have `base.send :alias_method_chain, :foo, :bar` which I cannot change without breaking current functionality (or don't know how to)

Comment: I am not sure about ur current requirement, can you post all the code so that i can look.

Comment: The code in question can be found here: https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/3.3-stable/lib/plugins/acts_as_customizable/lib/acts_as_customizable.rb#L44
The task is to create another structure acting exactly as the plugin in question, but storing data in a different DB schema.